# countable dense set of space of continuous functions on a campact set

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $C_+(X)$ be the set of all non negative continuous functions on $X$. Do there exist a countable dense set of $C_+(X)$?

I think the answer is affirmative. For example when $X=[a,b]$ we can think of rational polynomials and take its absolute values. But I cannot really find an analogous of polynomials for the general compact metric space.

Comment: The functions $f_y : x \mapsto d(x,y)$ play the analogous role. Just choose a countable dense set $\{y_n\}$ and take rational linear combinations of the $\{f_{y_n}\}$

Comment: First I want to find a subalgebra of such functions. It seems the product of two such linear combination is not again a linear combination...

Comment: If the space is such then it ia normal and second countable and hence it is embeddable in R^(infinity) by Uryson's Theorem. So the continuous function is completely determined on a countable subset of X. But if X itself [0,1} power [0,1] then this requirement is unlikely.